# Can I call a com object from a referenced .net library in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET on C# and I have a referanced library in the same solution in VB which calls a COM object using CreateObject.

When I run the site on my comp it works, when I run it on my IIS 6 it gives me a stackoverflow on the method call.

Now I have a script wich runs the VB code on the IIS6 and it works just fine.
It must be something with the ASP...

How can I call Com objects within ASP..., Do I have to do something special?

Pls help.

Comment: string handling code on a path maybe?

Comment: no can't sorry.
string handling code on the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was IIS using a different user than visual studio to run my web application, that use didn't have permissions to access all the reasources that my COM object used, such as a registry key, directories and files, + it was blocked of doing certain things in the "Local Security Policy" and in dcomcnfg.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reference to the Com file in your asp pages? the reference for the asp.net pages are in the `web.config` file.

Comment: how can i referance a Com, in the web config?

Comment: Should be here: `<compilation debug="true"><assemblies></assemblies></compilation>`. but I don't really sure since it not a good prectice to do it anyway.